# php image upload library

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, images, library

I'm looking to NOT reinvent the wheel with an image upload system in php.  Is there a good standalone library that allows for:

- Creating the system for uploading, renaming, and perhaps resizing images.
- Creating the front-end, html and/or javascript for the form upload parts of image upload.

I've found a lot of image gallery systems, but no promising standalone system & ui libraries, ready for insertion into custom php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this nice php image resize lib/function and integrated it with the form myself:

https://github.com/tchalvak/smart_resize_image

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this myself, but I use the TinyMCE text editor and it's pretty nice...

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php

From the site:

Key Features

```
* Easy to integrate.
* MCFileManager compatible.
* Create folders.
* Upload images.
* Crop & Resize (if GD is enabled).
* Thumbnail auto generation (if GD is enabled).
* EXIF jpg/jpeg and tiff thumbnail support.
* Highly customizable configuration.
* Works perfectly in fullscreen and "popup" mode.
* Full source included, not obfuscated.
* Ajax based interface using a JSON bridge.
* Multilanguage support.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out: http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

I have been using that class for several months now and simply put, it's the best I have come across for my requirements.